# Raspberry Pi Pico socket module error when trying to use Modbus in micropython

Tags: modbus, pi-pico, micropython

I want to use Modbus library in Pico. First of all, I just try `ModbusTCP` then `ModbusSerial`. I am trying to use this https://github.com/techbase123/micropython-modbus GitHub source.

When I run the `uModBusTcp.py` after add other modules, there is an error like `ImportError: no module named 'socket`  in Thonny.

What should I do ? I didn't find to install socket module.

Is there any suggesstion about it ? What should I try ?

Comment: But uModBus is for ESP32 only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realize that pi pico has no wi-fi. So, I just use modbusRTU with pi pico.